# Datalog+- doubt about semantics and complexity

Tags: database-theory, first-order-logic, datalog

I am reading about Datalog+- (e,g, https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5571709), and I have a doubt about its semantics, and about the complexity of query answering.

In Datalog+-, you write sets of TGDs whose chase is not guaranteed to terminate. However, Datalog+- guarantees that, for the problem of query answering, you can bound the number of chase steps you have to perform to solve the query.

First question:

- I understand that it is not necessary to compute the whole chase because null values will never be part of the answer because we are assuming some kind of certain-answers semantics (i.e., we only want to retrieve all the values that would be retrieved by any possible database satisfying the TGDs -i.e., a model-, and null values represents values that can take different values in different models). Is this right?

Second question:

- Suppose that we have a fixed set of TGDs, and a fixed query. Given a set of facts, why isn't the problem of query-answering polynomial? I mean, the number of facts (without nulls) that we can compute with the chase is polyniomial (it can be bounded by $n^k$, where n is the number of constants appearing in the facts, and k the maximum arity of the predicates, which is fix).

Is it the case that, despite the number of facts (without nulls) is polynomial, computing them might require computing a huge (non-polynomial) set of facts including nulls? If this is the case, can anyone give me some example?

Any help will be appreciated